# Usinq Linq to select items that is in a semi-comma separated string?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a string with semi-comma separated names:

```
string names = "Jane;Harry";
```

I also have a list of customer objects:

```
public class Customer
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}

List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
customers.Add(new Customer(){FirstName="John", LastName="Doe"});
customers.Add(new Customer(){FirstName="Jane", LastName="Doe"});
customers.Add(new Customer(){FirstName="Harry", LastName="Potter"});

var query = from c in customers
            select c;
```

How do I create a query that returns only those customers that has a first name that is in the semi-comma separated list?

Something like the T-SQL `SELECT FistName FROM customer WHERE FirstName IN (list)`
(sort of)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, you should really split the string up to start with - otherwise you'll get a match for "Jane" even if the list is "Janet;Harry".

You could do:

```
string[] validNames = names.Split(';');
var query = customers.Where(c => validNames.Contains(c.FirstName));
```

Another option is to use a `HashSet`, which will perform a lot better when the list is very large:

```
HashSet<string> validNames = new HashSet<string>(names.Split(';'));
var query = customers.Where(c => validNames.Contains(c.FirstName));
```

I've used dot notation here instead of a query expression because it's simpler when you're just applying a clause or two. As a query expression though, it would be:

```
var query = from c in customers
            where validNames.Contains(c.FirstName)
            select c;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

List firstnames = names.Split(';').ToList();

```
var query = from c in customers
            where firstnames.Contains(c.FirstName) 
            select c ;
```

Answer (score -1):

It Will Helps

```
string allid = "11,12,13,14,15,16";
string[] arrid = allid.Split(',');
var data = context.MyModels.Where(x => arrid.Contains(x.ProjectId.ToString()));
```

Comment: This don't add anything that is not in 10 y.o. accepted answer.