# Usinq Linq to search delimited list with another delimited list

Tags: c#, linq

I have comma delimited list that looks like this:

```
string roleSearch = "Admin,Buyer,Broker";
```

And I have a `List<Contacts>` that looks like this:

```
ContactID    Roles
----------------------------
   1        "Buyer,Partner"
   2        "Broker"
   3        "Admin,Buyer,Partner"
```

I am trying to write a query in Linq that will refine the `List<Contacts>` to items that contain *any* of the roles in `roleSearch`.  So given:

```
roleSearch = "Admin,Buyer"
```

I want any record where `Roles` contains "Admin" or "Buyer".  Both are not necessary. If either "Admin" or "Buyer" are present, then it's a positive.

Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536925/usinq-linq-to-select-items-that-is-in-a-semi-comma-separated-string), I got close:

```
string[] inRoles = roleSearch .Split(',');
results = results.Where(r => inRoles.Contains(r.Roles));
```

But that's not it exactly, because it only returns record with an exact match of each item in `inRoles`.  Meaning, it only returns records with a single role. Any row where `Roles` is something like "Admin,Partner" would be ignored.

I tried this:

```
string[] inRoles = roleSearch.Split(',');
results = results.Where(r => inRoles.Contains(r.Roles.Split(',')));
```

But that didn't work.

P.S.  I can't count on the roles being in any order.  BUT, good news, the list of potential roles is very small.  Five max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var test = results.Where(x => x.Roles.Split(',').Intersect(inRoles).Any()).ToList();
```

I'm using the [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) extension method to produce the set intersection of two sequences.

Comment: Any( r => inRoles.Contains( r ) ) is more efficient than Intersect(...).Any()